# delete a copied pointer

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Is deleting a copied pointer the same as deleting the original pointer?

```
int * a = new int;
*a = 8;
int *b = a;
delete b;
```

In the code above, after deleting `b`, should i still delete `a`?

In the real code I have problem with, i did

```
std::vector<ifstream * >Infiles(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
   ifstream * ptr = new ifstream;
   (*ptr).open(file_names[i].c_str());
   Infiles[i] = ptr;
}

/* doing a bunch of reading with Infiles */

for (int i = 0; i < Infiles.size(); ++i){
            delete Infiles[i]; // this part crashes
            Infiles[i] = NULL;
}
```

But the line `delete Infiles[i];` causes crashes, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Comment out the `/* doing a bunch of reading with Infiles */` code.  Does the code still crash?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are absolutely correct. Deleting through a pointer makes all pointers referencing the deleted object invalid. And the best way to avoid problems like this is to stop using owning pointers in C++ code.

By the way, this fact is the best reason **not to** set pointers to `nullptr` after deleting them - since it does nothing to other copies of the same pointer, it does not make the code any safer.